# mysql : error 1265 data truncated for column 'due_date' at row1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data into `book_loans` where `date_out` and `due_date` are dates.

Following is the query which I try to run but for `due_date`:

```
insert into book_loans(book_id2,branch_id1,card_no,date_out,due_date)
        values ('1565927699',4,9021, current_date(), current_date()+14)
```

it shows '0000-00-00' in due_date and the warning: `error 1265 data truncated for column 'due_date' at row1`.

I tried using `getdate()` but it gives an error of library does not exist.
what can be the problem?

Comment: What you are trying with `current_date()+14`?

Comment: current_date()+14 is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select **current_date()+14** give you a numeric value not the date value that's why data truncated and not inserted properly in the table.

You need to use **date_add()** function for inserting the current date + 14 days as:

```
date_add(current_date(), interval 14 day)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this command

```
select current_date()+14 from dual
```

you will see what is happend. The result is `20150737` what is not a correct date. That is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your adding 14 days to current date.These SQL useful to you.

```
INSERT INTO book_loans(book_id2,branch_id1,card_no,date_out,due_date)
            VALUES ('1565927699',4,9021, CURRENT_DATE(),  
                     DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY));
```

Thank You.